# WinForms Usercontrol resizing on its own on Build

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2013

I have a very strange issue and i hope somebody knows how to fix this, because it is more than annoying.

I can resize all of my user controls as much as I like in the designer. But as soon as the build process starts, all usercontrols that are not assigned with `dock = fill` are resized, which out me doing anything, to the size specified by the `minimumSize` property.

Where does this issue come from, because in other projects I do not have this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That problem *usually* comes from changing DPI settings (a form has been designed with different DPI than the currently running ones), generally setting `AutoScaleMode` to `None` on the misbehaving controls (and the form) will prevent that from happening (of course, that also prevents autofitting to different DPI settings).

The winforms designer needs a couple of tweaks here and there, but if I were you, I wouldn't expect anyone to fix it in a near future (... or in a far future, or ever at all)

Comment: where do I set the DPI? Because the controls in question where made by me, so I might be able to fix this

Comment: @lsteinme the DPI in Windows, not in the controls. If you designed the form while being at 96dpi in Windows, and are modifying it at 120dpi, with `AutoScaleMode` at other than `None`, weird things ocurr when the form is serialized (when saving or building). Basically, the designer expects you to be at 96dpi when working on it

Comment: so if I understand this right, the issue might be that i use two monitors with different resolutions for designing...

Comment: @lsteinme Definitely. The winforms designer already has problems with all monitors at the same DPI (when those DPI are not 96)... let alone different DPI on different monitors. There's not a lot you can do: if you want DPI-aware applications, you must design them at 96dpi... if you can pass without dpi-awareness, set `AutoScaleMode` to `None`. Some have reported success designing at other than 96dpi: personally? I have never succedeed at it (I just use WPF for dpi-aware apps)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue earlier, the method I use is, in your initialize component area, declare the size of your component in advance after deciding which size is the best.

Something like this:

```
InitializeComponent()
{
component1.size = new System.Drawing.Size(x,y);
}
```

Hope this helps in anyway... :)

Comment: Did you find out why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

Well, not yet, I faced another peculiar issue in Visual Studio 2015, where the form by itself would shrink... like totally when debugged... I believe it's got something to do with DPI settings... sometimes the manufacturer may set DPI levels to something that might make the most programs look normal on high res displays... VS probably has an issue with DPI settings... it's just what I could deduce...  try tinkering around that... and see if it helps.. I downgraded to VS 2013 though... and it's fine now